# There are an Object Key-Value Graph or Document Mapping solutions to use

Tags: database, orm, nosql

The are many solutions related with NoSql databases, like key-value, big table and graph models.

The advantage of this approach is the NoSql databases have a high performance to deal with a huge data and requisitions.

But my doubt is there are solutions like hibernate, jpa or similar to help the developers to deal with different kind of nosql solutions offering an abstraction layer or common interface to turn easy the development.

A kind of a Object "NoSql" Mapping  ...kkkk

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoSQL applications are designed around the database they use and NoSQL databases are finely tuned for particular workloads. If there were a common interface, it would defeat the object.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer, but that doesn't rule out specific solutions to the question.

Hibernate OGM does allow exposing specific features as API extensions for each individual technology it supports, like Hibernate ORM has always allowed and facilitated the use of "native" SQL statements.

The role of solutions like Hibernate OGM is to make it easier to get started, and deal with the 90% of business operations which are boring to code, error prone, and don't need to tap into the specific features. That should save people time and energy to spend on the features which matter, and implement the finely-tuned data access operations for the fewer operations which benefit from it.